# How to get month name with year for array data

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get the data for last 6 months (with year). Its working partially correct but now showing the month name with year if data is not available in database.

Output I am getting:

```
array:3 [▼
        "March 2022" => "742.90"
        "February 2022" => "70.00"
        "December 2021" => "450.00"
]
```

Output I am expecting:

```
array:3 [▼
        "March 2022" => "742.90"
        "February 2022" => "70.00"
        "January 2022" => "00.00"
        "December 2021" => "450.00"
        "November 2021" => "00.00"
        "October 2021" => "00.00"
]
```

Controller code:

```php
$fiveincomedata = Dairyincome::select(
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(milksaledate, "%M %Y") as "month_name", SUM(totalamount) as "totalamount", max(milksaledate) as milksaledate')
)
    ->whereBetween('milksaledate', [Carbon::now()->subMonth(6), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
    ->groupBy('month_name')
    ->orderBy('milksaledate', 'desc')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('totalamount','month_name','milksaledate')
    ->toArray();
```

Thanks in advace

Comment: You are not going to get that output as you have no rows with `Month Year` and `0.0`... you need to manipulate that on PHP after you got the data, or use Javascript. Also, passing a 3rd argument to `pluck` should do nothing.

Comment: The only way I can think of is running a for loop and adding a month each loop then checking if that month exists in your query or not then creating a new associative array with the data you got.

Comment: Thanks for Reply... I am new self leaner, So can u share some hint of code for loop. I tried but can not get success. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

You can try using whereNotNull / orWhereNotNull, if you'r using whereNotNull just use this code

```
->whereNotNull($month_name);
```

If you'r using orWhereNotNull use this code

```
->orWhereNotNull($month_name);
```